# Either create new array or increase counter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm iterating an array and whenever a specific condition becomes true, I want to either create a new array (within another array) or (if the array already exists) increase its value by 1:

```
for(var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
  if(condition==true){
      arr2[i] = ++ || []; // either increase by 1 or create new array
   }
}
```

My code gives me a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ||`.

Comment: What do you mean by 'increase the value of the array by one'?

Comment: Your unexpected token is `||` = `OR` so that needs to be a conditional inside parentheses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you mean create a new array value & increment it if it exists:

```
for(var i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
  if(condition==true){
      arr2[i] = (arr2[i] || 0) + 1; // either increase by 1 or initialize
   }
}
```

Comment: I understood the question as arr2[i] is an array, not a number.